# How do you limit the No. of chars with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making a blog site, on the home page I wont to display the first 50 characters of the blog description, how do I do that with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You might want to be a *little* more specific...

Answer (score 1):

string.substring(Math.Min(string.length, 50)) might be a starting point.